# If...Else Statements within quotes in PHP

Tags: php

i want to use some conditions in my variable but its not working please give me a solution
so that i can use some PHP code

```
$html = '<table>
<tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Month</th>
                <th colspan="2">No of Emp.</th
               '.if(){}.'              
</tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: Use a temporary variable. Make the check, before assembling the HTML. Then use the temporary variable whe building the HTML.

Comment: ok, lemme try it

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz
i want to use while condition there how can i?

Comment: If you put your code _above_ the HTML building part, you can use anything...

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz can you send example code

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz and actually i added the code above it and it doesn't give the desired result

Comment: Can you please update your question? Example for a while loop is too basic, if you're having troubles how to write code, please make some tutorials first.

Comment: you're doing it wrong by placing a bunch of HTML in a variable, if you break out of PHP then use output buffering to capture the output, it will be much cleaner `ob_start() ?> <table... /> <?php $html = ob_end_clean();` then you can just do the html/php instead of  concatenating and building up an output.. additionally if you just doing `echo $html;` at the end of it, you don't need to even build the string in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to to break you code into sections, and build your table.
Maybe in a separate "helper function". Example follows.

```
$html = '<table>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">Month</th>
<th colspan="2">No of Emp.</th>';

  if($month = 'december'){
    $html .= "<tr><td>$month</td><td>$num_employeees</td></tr>";              
  }
$html .= '</tr>
</table>';
```